# Browsersync doesn't set the right local url

Tags: wordpress, browser-sync

I'm working on a Wordpress project using the starter theme [Roots with Gulp](https://github.com/roots/roots/tree/8.0.0) in association with MAMP PRO. I'm experiencing a problem with the 'watch' task from the gulpfile.js.
Here below is the code of the task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  browserSync({
    proxy: "mywebsite:8888",
    port: 8888,
    open: "internal"
  });
  gulp.watch([path.source + 'styles/**/*'], ['styles']);
  gulp.watch([path.source + 'scripts/**/*'], ['jshint', 'scripts']);
  gulp.watch(['bower.json'], ['wiredep']);
  gulp.watch('**/*.php', function() {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
});
```

And this is the terminal output after launching the 'gulp watch' command:

```
gulp watch
[12:46:32] Using gulpfile ~/Dropbox/_sites/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/mywebsitetheme/gulpfile.js
[12:46:32] Starting 'watch'...
[12:46:37] Finished 'watch' after 4.26 s
[BS] Proxying: http://mywebsite:8888
[BS] Now you can access your site through the following addresses:
[BS] Local URL: http://localhost:8888
[BS] External URL: http://192.168.22.168:8888
```

As a result browsersync open, with my default browser, the url http://localhost:8888.

What I need now is, basically, that the resulting url (opened by the browser) is http://mywebsite:8888.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved thanks to bower community member ([github issue](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/453))
I just need to delete any configuration option and add the snippet below before the  closing tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript' id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='//HOST:PORT/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.1.0.js'><\/script>".replace(/HOST/g, location.hostname).replace(/PORT/g, location.port));
//]]></script>
```